# it is very wired that the inferencing time of bert increase after converted to onnx

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

**obey the stantard process of coverting model to ONNX, the inferencing time actually increased, and

i have checked the output of onnx that is equal to that of bert. except bert, other model like MLP can normally reduce inference time by onnx, so why this happen?**

```
class qwe(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, path):
    super(qwe,self).__init__()
    self.bert=BertModel.from_pretrained(path)
    self.ll=nn.Linear(768,10)

def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids):
    out=self.bert(input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids)[1]
    out=self.ll(out)
    return out

input_ids=torch.from_numpy(np.random.randint(1,500,(1,512))).to(torch.long)
attention_mask=torch.from_numpy(np.ones((1,512))).to(torch.long)
token_type_ids=torch.tensor(np.zeros((1,512))).to(torch.long)

inputs=(input_ids, attention_mask, token_type_ids)
input_dict={
    'input_ids':np.random.randint(1,500,(1,512), dtype=np.long),
    'attention_mask':np.ones((1,512), dtype=np.long),
    'token_type_ids':np.zeros((1,512), dtype=np.long)
}

model=qwe(path)
model.eval()
torch.onnx.export(
    model,
    f=ONNX,
    args=inputs,
    opset_version=12,
    export_params=True,
    input_names=['input_ids','attention_mask','token_type_ids'],
    output_names=['output'],
    dynamic_axes={'input_ids':[0],'attention_mask':[0],'token_type_ids':[0]}
)
sesssion=onnxruntime.InferenceSession(ONNX,  providers=['CPUExecutionProvider'])
with torch.no_grad():
    start_time = time.time()
    output = sesssion.run(None, input_dict)
    print('onnx  ： {}'.format(time.time() - start_time))
    st=time.time()
    res=model(torch.tensor(input_dict['input_ids'] ,dtype=torch.long),
          torch.tensor(input_dict['attention_mask'], dtype=torch.long),
          torch.tensor(input_dict['token_type_ids'], dtype=torch.long))
    print('torch  : {}'.format(time.time() - st))
```

---

```
bert : 0.45925045013427734
onnx  ： 0.5993204116821289
```

---

```
bert_output
tensor([[ 1.1763,  0.2471,  1.0245,  0.1245, -0.5310, -0.6783, -0.1928, -0.1242,
     -0.0139,  0.9107]])
onnx_output
[array([[ 1.1763551 ,  0.24712242,  1.0244701 ,  0.12455264, -0.5310014 ,
    -0.67832315, -0.19275273, -0.12419312, -0.01386394,  0.91070646]],
  dtype=float32)]
```

Answer (score 0):

i have figured it out. my environment is python3.6, in which onnx doesn't perform well. and with the same code, onnx enjoy a 50% inferencing speed up in python3.7.